# Docker-compose create database but not table

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, devops

I'm currently facing an issue :
I am trying to dockerize a node API with a db mySQL, and i want to generate the db when i type my command docker-compose up --build.

My ***dockerFile*** :

```
FROM node:slim
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install netcat
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["sh", "wait.sh"]
```

My ***dockercompose*** for db :

```
  db:
    build: ./dockerDb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - db_volume:/var/lib/mysql
    network_mode: host
```

My ***dockerifle mysql*** :

```
FROM mysql:5.7
EXPOSE 3306
COPY dump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

***dump.sql*** :

```
CREATE DATABASE library;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Book`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Book` (
  `ISBN` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  ...
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `Book` (`ISBN`, ...) VALUES
('1111111111111', ...),
('2222222222222', ...),
('3333333333333', ...);
```

**My problem is :** the docker is created correctly, but it only creates the db library and does not create the table Book inside.
I tested this mysql code on PhpMyAdmin and it works.
So i do not inderstand what i am doing wrong.

My project organisation:
[projectOrganisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjLrk.png)

If someone has an advice, i would be happy.

Respectfluly.

Comment: Try putting `USE library;` as the second line of `dump.sql`.